# Integrate a wordpress blog with Rails4 (+host on heroku). Most Preferred way in Rails?

Tags: wordpress, heroku, seo, ruby-on-rails-4, blogs

I have a rails application (Rails4, postgres, haml, twitter bootstrap) hosted on heroku.

I looked around and most of the solutions are older so I am specifically asking for Rails4.

I want to have a blog on my website like : http:/myapp.com/blog/1 etc

From what I understand so far the simplest way to do this is:
1] Use https://github.com/mhoofman/wordpress-heroku to create and host a blog on heroku.
2] Follow these steps to integrate them http://rywalker.com/setting-up-a-wordpress-blog-on-heroku-as-a-subdirectory-of-a-rails-app-also-hosted-on-heroku

My requirements are very simple so far:
1] I am creating this blog to increase engagement and get more inbound traffic.
2] For most purposes the blog and website will never talk to each other.
3] Will like to add different wordpress themes etc to make blog more likeable.
4] Is hosted on the same domain (http://myapp.com)

I am sure thousands of websites have done this. So what is the most preferred and simplest setup which gets me started quickly and has lot of community support behind it. It's completely fine if the preferred setup adds some constraints.